# Xamarin TemplatedBinding not working with attached Property

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, attached-properties, templatebinding

So I have a simple `TableView` in Xamarin where each row connects to a ControlTemplate. I wanted to set some attributes using attached properties on the ControlTemplate from the `ViewCells` however, no matter what I try the TemplateBindings seem to ignore the attached Properties.

So here is the ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ResultTemplate">
            <StackLayout Margin="20,0,20,0"
                         BackgroundColor="{TemplateBinding attachableProperties:ColorProperties.BackgroundColor}">
                <StackLayout Margin="0,5,0,0">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    <controls:Separator />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I Connect to this Template with the following piece of code from inside a ViewCell:

```
<ViewCell>
          <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ResultTemplate}"
                       attachableProperties:ColorProperties.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource OddRowBackgroundColor}">
                <Label Text="Hi" />
          </ContentView>
</ViewCell>
```

Finally here is the code for the attached property:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
        "BackgroundColor",
        typeof(Color),
        typeof(ColorProperties),
        Color.Red,
        propertyChanged: ((bindable, value, newValue) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);
        }));

    public static Color GetBackgroundColor(BindableObject obj)
    {
        return (Color) obj.GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBackgroundColor(BindableObject obj, Color value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value);
    }
```

I've added the `Debug.Writeline` to the `propertyChanged` parameter to see if it gets called, and so it does. So the problem in my opinion does have to lie with the TemplateBinding. But why does it not work, I can not get my head around why the TemplateBinding does not connect to the attached property.

Comment: Hi, did you have some updates?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your logic code in `propertyChanged`:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BackgroundColorProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
"BackgroundColor",
typeof(Color),
typeof(ColorProperties),
Color.Red,
propertyChanged: ((bindable, value, newValue) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value);

    var control = bindable as View;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.BackgroundColor = (Color)newValue;
    }
}));
```